# Trail effect in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

Sir,

Refer the below link which specifies what i achieve upto now using ccRibbon class.I need some little bit improvement in that one.Any ideas intimate me.Instead of fading a streak i like to move it wherever touch process has been carried out.Thanks.

"http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/4044/fromphixrwe.jpg"

"http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/8497/fromphixrkq.jpg"

Comment: Touch process carried out; intimating ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "trail effect" in Fruit Ninja would be best accomplished by using a custom particle effect.  You can create particle effects using Particle Designer (http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) and then integrate them into your Cocos2D project using the appropriate CCParticle* classes (ie; a derived class of CCParticleSystem specific to your particle effect).

You could also look into creating your own version of CCMotionStreak by implementing CCRibbon yourself.